# extract listening TCP port from iproute2 ss output

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like to find the port that a process (for example apache2) is listening on and print only this (tcp) port number to a file, file1.txt.

- Here is the command I tried:

  ```
  $ ss -atpln | grep 'apache2' | awk -F':' '{print $2}' > file1.txt
  ```
- Here is my output (to file1.txt):

  ```
  80     *
  ```

How can I ensure that only the port number (80), NOT the  '*', is my output?

---

Edit by Ed Morton to add the important information the OP provided in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662922/scripting-with-find-and-awk#comment1246967_662924):

Please note that this sequence from my system:

```
$ ss -atpln | grep apache2
```

Output is:

```
LISTEN 0 511 *:80 *:* users:(("apache2",pid=55338,fd=4),("apache2",pid=55337,fd=4),("apache2",pid=856,fd=4))
```

Comment: Add the output of `ss -atpln | grep 'apache2` to your question.

Comment: One solution is to use one of awk's text processing functions such as `sub` to get rid of the ` *` part of the output. Another is piping awk's output into sed, with a regular expression that strips ` *` from the text. You can also use awk with the default field separator, then strip `.*:` from the output. There are certainly more solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# ss -atpln | awk -F ':|[[:blank:]]+' '/apache2/ {print $5}'
443
443
443
80
80
80
```

This uses either a colon or one-or-more "blank" characters (i.e. spaces or tabs) as the field separator, which means the field we want to print (the port number) is now field 5.

There's no need to use `grep` if you're already using `awk` - awk is quite capable of doing pattern matches without grep's help.

The output should probably be piped into `sort -u` to print only unique port numbers.

BTW, if you're wondering why the sample output has three lines each of 443 and 80, on my system apache2 is configured to listen on ports 80 and 443 for three different IP addresses (for three different vhosts), not just on `*:80` and `*:443`.

Comment: Much appreciated; thank you.

Comment: I tried this recommended command: ss -atpln | awk -F ':|[[:blank:]]+' '/apache2/ {print $2}', however, the output was the same as in my original question. PS: I changed the {print $5} to {print $2} because the former did not have any output.

Comment: Please note that this sequence from my system: $ ss -atpln | grep apache2.       Output is: 
LISTEN   0         511                       *:80                     *:*        users:(("apache2",pid=55338,fd=4),("apache2",pid=55337,fd=4),("apache2",pid=856,fd=4))

Comment: @WildGTX please edit your question and include this. We can't help you parse data that you do not show us.

Comment: WildGTX I added the info from your comment to your question. If I got it wrong in any way then of course please edit your question to fix it. Based on the information you've provided so far @cas's answer should do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @EdMorton and Cas - I have been tinkering with this problem with your suggested solution and I am still getting the * in my output. Please consider the full output I provided earlier when I issue the command $ ss -atpln | grep apache2. Notice that I have both "*:80" and "*:*" The issue I am having is coming from output of the * in the  *:* How do I avoid this * from being captured in my output? And any advise for where I can get a good tutorial on awk and sed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that you're using `nawk` or some other out of date awk variant which doesn't support POSIX character classes. Try changing `-F ':|[[:blank:]]+'` to `-F ':|[ \t]+'`. To learn how to use AWK the right way get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton

Comment: You're welcome. If that doesn't work then there's something non-obvious about the output of `ss -atpln` that doesn't actually look like what's currently shown in your question.

Comment: I piped your example output into my awk script above and the output was `80`.   I tried this with GNU awk, GNU awk with --posix/--traditional, mawk, original-awk, and busybox awk - all with the same result, it works (I tried nawk too, but on my Debian system that's just a symlink to gnu awk, so that's to be expected).  Maybe your awk doesn't like alternation in the field separator, try `-F '[: \t]+'`, which will match one-or-more of :, space, or tab.  What version of awk are you running?

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for the last suggestion to try -F '[: \t]+'. That worked! So the issue must be in the version of awk I am running, which is mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan. Thanks again to everyone, esp. EdMorton, for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome. That's an extremely outdated, minimal featured version awk (it was designed as such to improve execution speed), you should get a newer one, preferably gawk but there are even recent mawk versions available with much more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `perl` and do a more explicit matching of the input to extract the info:

```
ss -Otpln |
  perl -slne '
    print $1 if m{
      ^ LISTEN \s+ # State
        \d+ \s+    # Recv-Q
        \d+ \s+    # Send-Q
        (?: 0\.0\.0\.0 | \[::\] | \*) : (\d+) \s+ # source address on INADDR_ANY
                                                  # or INADDR6_ANY only
        \S+ \s+    # dest address
        users: .* \(" \Q$name\E ",pid # match on process name
      }x && ! $already_seen{$1}++' -- -name=apache2
```

Your output format is different from mine (I get `0.0.0.0` for the wildcard IPv4 address and `[::]` for the IPv6 one while you get `*`), suggesting the `ss` output format may not be very stable. Instead of `ss`, you could use `lsof` which has a mode intended for batch processing and can do the matching by process name:

```
lsof -Fn -wnMPa -c apache2 -i tcp -s tcp:listen |
  sed -n 's/^n\*://p' |
  sort -nu
```

It would also make it portable to non-Linux systems.